# I found an Excel configuration error: Unable to get the Object property of the OLEObject class

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know about OLEObject's nature and where OLEObject is located. I'm not a VBA programmer, but an VBA developer in my office found that error message, and she can't run the Excel VBA program in question on her machine.  This program runs completely in another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first ensure [ActiveX controls are enabled](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/enable-or-disable-activex-controls-in-office-documents-HA010031067.aspx) on her machine.  This has been, in my experience, the typical cause when a VBA program will run on one machine but not another.

You could also:

- Try activating the object first by using `.Activate` beforehand
- Try referencing the object by its index rather than name